# GCE ingress resource is taking too long to receive an IP address in GKE cluster. What could be the reason?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I am trying to deploy a sample application on GKE cluster. All the resources are getting created successfully except the ingress resource which is taking around 15-20 minutes to receive an ip address. By this time application times out and get in errored state. The ideal time to assign the IP addr is 2-3 minutes. Can anyone help on the issue how to debug it?
This is happening specific to a cluster while the same ingress getting the ip within 2 minutes in other clusters in GKE.

Below the manifest files I am using to deploy app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zone-printer-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zone-printer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zone-printer
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zone-printer
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/zone-printer:0.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zone-printer-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: zone-printer
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    targetPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: awesome-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: hello-service
      port:
        number: 8000
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:      
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello-service
            port:
              number: 8000
      - path: /zone-printer
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: zone-printer-service
            port:
              number: 9000
```

Comment: I think you should reach out to customer support for this. they might be able to help you!

Comment: What's the version of the GKE cluster where it takes too long ? The ingress controller (The component of GKE that provisions the LoadBalancer when you deploy an Ingress object) is tight to the GKE version. Maybe you are running an old GKE version with an old Ingress controller ?

Comment: @boredabdel The GKE cluster version I am using is 1.21.12-gke.1500 and Ingress controller api version is networking.k8s.io/v1 which is latest.

Comment: networking.k8s.io/v1 is the upstream Ingress API version. That's not the version of the controller. 

Can you check the version of other clusters where the provisioning of Ingress is faster and compare this one ?

Comment: @boredabdel the other clusters version is also same as 1.21.12-gke.1500. I don't know why the issue coming specific to this cluster. Also, can you please let me know how to check controller version as I couldn't able to find anything for it.

Comment: The controller version is correlated to the cluster version and there is really no way for you to check that.  My best advice would be to open a ticket with support and let them handle that.